# php doesn't execute after dompdf

Tags: php, dompdf

php doesn't execute after dompdf stream
I'm trying to print echo Hello after $dompdf->stream("ABC.pdf") but it doen't work

```
  include_once("../assets/converter/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
  $dompdf =  new DOMPDF();
  $dompdf->load_html("<html><body>Hello</body></html>");
  $dompdf->render();
  $dompdf->stream("ABC.pdf");

  echo "Hello"
```

even after error_reporting(E_ALL); i don't see any error

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: had you checked error log? please provide more details.

Comment: sorry even after error_reporting(E_ALL); i get no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's normal as `$dompdf->stream("ABC.pdf");` creates and sends the PDF with the headers directly to the browser. So, after this point you can't execute other instructions on the script

Comment: yeah it could be that

Comment: if echo "Hello" above include_once Hello is included in pdf and pdf is corrupted.I want to echo "Hello" and let client download PDF

Comment: you can't do that in the same script. You could send the user to a page with an echo "hello" and then (for example after a javascript countdown in that page) call the script that renders and streams the PDF